# Eclipse IDE Questions: Auto Content Assist for Apex and Apex Hotkeyed Help (CTRL+F1)

Tags: apex, visualforce, ide, eclipse

I hope this is okay to ask in this section. I decided to try out Eclipse for my IDE for salesforce development work (been using Sublime + MavensMate) and there are two things that I've been unable to figure out:

First - I would like to have the content assist pop-up automatically as I type. I can hit CTRL+spacebar to get it to pop-up, but I would really like it to pop-up automatically like it does in Sublime. I've searched in Eclipse's preferences related to this, but I've been unable to find an option that would turn this on. Is this something that I can turn on? Or is there a plugin that I should be using for this?

Second - I would like to be able to select a word and hit CTRL-F1 to get help on that word in my code. When I hit CTRL+F1 on a word, it opens Help, but then I have to manually type in what I'm looking for to get help. The help appears to be there, but I have to do the searching manually. Is there a way to set this up so that I can just leverage the hotkey to search for what I've selected?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Last I checked the code assistance in Eclipse wasn't using the newer Tooling API like MavensMate does. As such I believe it is very limited. Is there a reason you are going to Eclipse? Most people I've noticed are going in the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

did u check this
go to preferences, Java/Editor/Content Assist, and edit the "Auto activation triggers for Java" field.